# Crash with Core data

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have a crash and in the my console i get this error :

```
Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x6d30540 {metadata=<CFBasicHash 0x6d2c680 [0x171bb38]>{type = immutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
.....
.....

reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
```

Do you see the reason for this, i am sorry i am new to Core Data.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your application on the device, delete the derived data via the Organizer and deploy again. You get this error, when you change your core data model and have an old build left on your device. So you need to delete the current build on your device every time you build after the core data model has changed.

More information can be found in the [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you changed the data model without updating the database itself.  If you have a prepopulated DB then your then it doesnt match your model.  If you dont then you need to do a clean install to create a new DB.